# One 100% height column split into 3 sections: 2 fixed and 1 fluid 

Tags: javascript, css, layout

I need to make a single div that takes up 100% of the window height to create a sidebar. This is easy. But is there a way to then split that column into 3, with a fixed height 1st and 3rd section with the middle section expanding to fill the remaining space on load and when the browser is resized with just CSS, without having to resort to javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you stick three divs within the sidebar and the sidebar has a CSS position of 'relative' then you can set the CSS for the three inner divs as follows:

```
#divTop {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
height: 120px;
}
#divMiddle {
position: absolute;
top: 120px;
bottom: 120px;
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
height: auto;
}
#divBottom {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px; /* EDIT: corrected from 120px; */
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
height: 120px;
}
```

Comment: #divBottom.bottom needs to be 0px.  Otherwise it'll be offset 120 px (120px space at bottom + 120px for the height)

Answer (score 1):

I know you accepted an answer. I'm adding this for future reference. You can also do what you want with the css `display:table` style. Not supported in IE7, but... maybe you don't care.

Use a container div, and then three child divs, like this:

```
<div id='container'>
  <div id='col1'> <h1>content for col1</h1> </div>
  <div id='col2'> <h1>content for col2</h1> </div>
  <div id='col3'> <h1>content for col3</h1> </div>
</div>
```

The css looks like this:

```
#container {
  display:table;
}
#container > div {
  display:table-cell;
  padding:4px 8px;
}
#col1 {
  width:160px;
  background-color:LightGreen;
}
#col2 {
  background-color:LightBlue;
}

#col3 {
  width:240px;
  background-color:LightPink;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CtEya/embedded/result/